# 404 Error on running custom module Helloworld in magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, module, 404

I am beginer in magento .I tried to made to made Helloworld custom module but get 404 error each time.

**This my custom module structure**

[image: This my custom module structure]

**This is `Chiragdodia_Mymodule.xml`  in app/etc/modules**

[image: This is Chiragdodia_Mymodule.xml in app/etc/modules]

**This is `config.xml` in `app/code/local/Chiragdodia/Mymodule/etc`**

[image: This is config.xml in app/code/local/Chiragdodia/Mymodule/etc]

**This is `IndexController.php` in `app/code/local/Chiragdodia/Mymodule/controllers`**

[image: this is IndexController.php in app/code/local/Chiragdodia/Mymodule/controllers]

I used this blog https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643

Caches are disabled . I tried these urls

> www.example.com/mymodule
>
> www.example.com/mymodule/index
>
> www.example.com/index.php/mymodule/index
>
> www.example.com/index.php/mymodule/index/index

But getting same 404 error each time.
any help will be appreciate

Comment: in controller use die(); after echo and check, if it echos then 404 error is due to the missing layout

Comment: I added die but no change .i'm  still getting 404 error

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, your module files are coming under `printer\send` directory. However your files should come under `app\code\local\Chiragdodia\Mymodule`.

Please take extra care of the Camel case letters above. For Magento, `Chiragdodia` and `chiragdodia` are not same.

Comment: thanks Rajeev. that structure picture I uploaded by mistake. now i changed.

Comment: and yes i checked all  Camel case  letters all are correct all are Chiragdodia .

Answer (score 0):

Sir,
According to my analysis the main issue are as follows

- First, your keyword are not the same as you deployed, means the keyword are case sensitive and you are using first letter as capital
- After completing all the thing just re-index the site data from 
  step 1 : `cd [MAGENTO_ROOT]/shell/`
  step 2 : `ls -l`
  "`php indexer.php --status`"
  step 3 : `php indexer.php --reindex` (index file name)

  > index file name:
- catalog_product_attribute Product Attributes
- catalog_product_price Product Prices
- catalog_url Catalog Url Rewrites
- catalog_product_flat Product Flat Data
- catalog_category_flat Category Flat Data
- catalog_category_product Category Products
- catalogsearch_fulltext Catalog Search Index
- cataloginventory_stock Stock status

OR to reindex all 
command: "`php indexer.php --reindexall`"